# Failing Deserialization due to dynamically added namespaces on serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have an object we serialize and deserialize. While serializing object we add namespace dynamically which does not exists in class definition as an attribute. I created small example to repeat the problem here:

I have a class, called Person:

```
[XmlRoot("person")]
public class Person
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime? dob { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("dobs")]
    public DateTime dobser { get{return dob.Value;} set{dob=value;} }

    public bool ShouldSerializedobser()
    {
        return dob.HasValue;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeName()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name);
    }

    public int? Age { get; set; }

}
```

And here the code serialize and deserialize,

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         var person = new Person();
         person.Age = 12;
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
         //add namespace
         XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
         namespaces.Add("ns1", "http://www.microsoft.com/schema/ml/v1");
         XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
         xs.Serialize(sw, person,namespaces);

         // try to deserialize, it fails. It is working If I don't add namespace
         xs.Deserialize(GenerateStreamFromString(sb.ToString()));

         Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
         Console.Read();
    }
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Yeah, it looks encoding problem, both comment are useful, thanks. I wish to mark your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Code posted works fine for me; I had to invent my own `GenerateStreamFromString`, but: no issues. Are you sure the problem isn't problems with unicode / BOMs?

For info, my invented method is:

```
private static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
{
    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value));
}
```

although actually I'd prefer:

```
private static XmlReader GenerateReaderFromString(string value)
{
    return XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(value));
}
```

(which is more direct; less overhead)

As a final note: you know that `<person>` isn't *in* that namespace, right? Your code just declares an alias that is never used. If the *actual* code is trying to deserialize a `<person>` **in the cited namespace**, then yes: that won't work (but: that is not what the code in the question shows)